# Передача параметров в компонент, создаваемый в react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Использую библиотеку `react-router` для навигации в SPA на базе React. Само приложение имеет вид:

**application.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Home from './home.jsx';

export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        // Объект пользователя. Здесь не важно, откуда именно он берется.
        const user = {name: 'FooBarBaz'};

        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={Home} />
            </Router>
        );
    }
});
```

**home.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';

export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (<div>You are {this.props.user.name}</div>);
    }
});
```

Вопрос заключается в том, как именно *пробросить* объект пользователя (`user`) компоненту `Home`?

---

Использую `react-router@2.4.1` и `react@15.1.0`

Comment: Использовать mobx или redux.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Реакт позволяет использовать чистые функции в качестве компонентов. Это дает вам возможность *обернуть* компонент `Home` добавив туда любые свойства.

Код приложения может выглядеть, например, так:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Home from './home.jsx';

export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        const user = {name: 'FooBarBaz'};

        // Это всего лишь обертка для компонента Home, позволяющая передавать
        // дополнительные параметры через замыкание.
        const WrappedHome = function(props) {
            // Конструкция "{...props}" нужна, чтобы не потерять
            // параметры, переданные от компонента Route
            return (<Home {...props} user={user} />);
        };

        // Обратите внимание на замену "Home" на "WrappedHome" в параметре
        // "component".
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={WrappedHome} />
            </Router>
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

То, что сказано в ответе Выше можно записать, чуть иначе. Возможно кому-то так будет удобнее:

**Суть решения** в том, что внутри `<Route />` мы заменяем:

```
    component={Home}
```

на

```
    render={()=><Home user={user}/>}
```

Для наглядности, в примере выше я убрал props, которые передает по умолчанию React-router. Если Вы их используете (а Вы скорее всего будете их использовать, то используете вот такую запись:

```
    render={(props)=><Home user={user} {..props}/>}
```

Обратите внимание, что "эти `(props)` и {...props}" не связаны с передачей данных `user`, которые мы хотим передать в props компонента Home и использовать как `this.props.user`.
В итоге получается так:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
    import Home from './home.jsx';

    export default React.createClass({
        render() {
            const user = {name: 'FooBarBaz'};

            // значение переменной user будет передано в компонет Home 
            // И в компоненте Home Вы сможете использовать this.props.user 
            return (
                <Router history={browserHistory}>
                    <Route path="/"  render={(props)=><Home user={user} {...props}/>}  />
                </Router>
            );
        }
    });
```

Внутри рендер вы видите `(props)` и `(...props)` — они не имеют отношения к тем props , которые мы хотим передать в Home для использования в виде `this.props.user`
`(props)` и `(...props)` это данные, которые передает компоненту Home бибилотека react-router.
Вы из не используете, можно их убрать, получится:

```
                <Router history={browserHistory}>
                    <Route path="/"  render={()=><Home user={user}/>}  />
                </Router>
```

**P.S.**
Еще раз, хотел бы уточить про {...props}
React-router по умолчанию в каждый компонент передает props (Это match, location, history, и т.д.).
Наша задача состоит в том, чтобы помимо этих данных, также передать какие-то свои данные.
Но это **не получается**, сделать так, как хотелось бы интуитивно:

```
    <Route path="/" component={component} someUserProps="какие-то наши данные" />`
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто обернуть компонент c "пропсами" тэгом `Route`:

```
<Route path="/"> <Home user={user}/> </Route>
```